# Filtering the dropdown options

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, filter, drop-down-menu

I need to update automatically several Drop-downs filtering the options from database for the next Dropdown. I'm using in my website jquery, javascript, ajax, php.

Its very common in websites with driver downloads, for example:

[Acer](http://www.acer.pt/ac/pt/PT/content/drivers)

[Samsung](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads/)

Thanks in advance

**Update:**

I'm using this code snippet: http://www.pedrocorreia.net/mySnippets/php/Actualizar-DropDownList-Utilizando-Ajax ,but I have some problems to adapt the code for more than 2 dropboxes.

**I'm looking for any example, tutorial or plugin.**

Comment: I think you forgot to post your current code :)

Comment: The basic concept is that when the user selects something, you request the suboptions from PHP and create another select box when you get the response.

Comment: You can also do it without a server call if the sets of data don't change.

Comment: I'm using this code snnipet with the problem that I need more than 2 dropboxes: http://www.pedrocorreia.net/mySnippets/php/Actualizar-DropDownList-Utilizando-Ajax

Comment: The sets of data will change, so I need a server call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look here for a codesnippet using html, jquery and php

http://codeassembly.com/Simple-chained-combobox-plugin-for-jQuery/

Answer (score 1):

after the user selected a value from the first dropdown you send the selected value to a php script (ajax!) and generate the valid dropdownoptions for your next dropdown. then you insert the values recieved from the server with jquery.

you should disable all dropdowns, which are not meant to be used because there was no selection in a previous dropdown yet.

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax to get ddl2 data on selection change of ddl1. Use jquery for ajax call, option add and event handling.